# How to create checked and unchecked exceptions that extend a base class?

Tags: java, exception

I am writing a java library. I want to use my own exceptions. I want to support both checked and unchecked exceptions, but I want both of them to derive from the same custom base class.
For example:

- `MyCheckedException`
- `MyUncheckedException`

I want both of them to extend `MyBaseException` which provides additional functionality. The problem is that the only way I know to make unchecked exception is extending the `RuntimeException` class. So here comes the task: how to make unchecked exception without extending `RuntimeException`, because my class must extend `MyBaseException` and therefore can not extend another class?

Comment: I doubt this can be done.

Comment: Cant, need to extend one or the other for checked or unchecked. Why do you need to extend it? Maybe what you want can be achieved by composition?

Comment: Consider using composition over inheritance - for example, [UncheckedIOException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/UncheckedIOException.html) adapts _IOException_.

Comment: Yes I can think of couple of workarounds. But the idea is that MyBaseException provides some fields which are common and useful to both MyCheckedException and MyUncheckedException. I just didn't want to copy-paste the same code in these classes.
Compositions is kind of inconvenient since I can not "throw" something that "is" not an Exception but "has an" Exception.

Comment: If your unchecked exception always _has a_ checked exception then the functionality would be available to exception handlers by calling _getCause()_ on the unchecked exception.